# LPTHW ex 40 not working? (Dictionary exercise, does not return key:value pair.)

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key-value

I have triple checked my code and as far as I can tell it is substantively identical to ex40 given in the book (LPTHW, Python 2.7):

```
cities = {'CA': 'San Francisco', 'MI': 'Detroit', 'FL': 'Jacksonville'}

cities['NY'] = 'New York'
cities['OR'] = 'Portland'

def find_city(themap, state):
        if state in themap:
            return themap[state]
    else:
        return "Not found."

cities['_find'] = find_city

while True:
    print "State? (ENTER to quit)",
    state = raw_input("> ")

    if not state: break

city_found = cities['_find'](cities, state)
print city_found
```

The expected output is something like this:

```
State? (ENTER to quit) > CA
San Francisco
State? (ENTER to quit) > FL
Jacksonville
State? (ENTER to quit) > O
Not found.
State? (ENTER to quit) > OR
Portland
State? (ENTER to quit) > VT
Not found.
State? (ENTER to quit) >
```

But when I run it, the input line just repeats until I hit enter on a blank line, never producing a city.  Like so:

```
State? (Enter to quit) > KS
State? (Enter to quit) > NY
State? (Enter to quit) > LA
State? (Enter to quit) > CA
State? (Enter to quit) > 
Not found.
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm overlooking?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The lines

```
city_found = cities['_find'](cities, state) # Better: city_found = find_city(cities, state)
print city_found
```

need to be inside the `while` loop, not after it.

I don't understand at all what the purpose of `cities['_find'] = find_city` is - why not call that function directly instead of adding it to the city dictionary? Seems extremely unpythonic to me.

Comment: Thanks, spacing visually looked different on the new page and I didn't check space from the line number.  As far as not calling the function directly I think it's pedagogical, showing how to build a function into a dictionary.

Comment: @themagicbean That makes sense, but it's a terrible example, to be honest. Putting functions into a dictionary can be useful, for example when you have to choose dynamically which function to call depending on context. But then you would have one dictionary for the functions and another one for your data. Mixing that stuff up is confusing.